# Showing that $x^{p}+y^{p}=z^{p}$ has no solutions when $p\nmid x,y,z$ and $p<23$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to show that $x^{p}+y^{p}=z^{p}$ when $3\neq p<23$ (I have already shown the case for $p=3$) and $p\nmid x,y,z$.

(1) I first need to show that $x+y\xi_{p}=\mu\alpha^{p}$, where $\xi_{p}$ is the $p$-th roots of unity, $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[\xi_{p}]$, and $\mu\in\mathbb{Z}[\xi_{p}]$ is a unit.

(2) Then I need to show that this implies $x\equiv y\bmod{p}$.

The remainder of the proof:
Suppose there are solutions for such primes $p$. By (1), $x+y\xi_{p}=\mu\alpha^{p}$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[\xi_{p}]$ and unit $\mu\in\mathbb{Z}[\xi_{p}]$. Since $x$ and $y$ are not divisible by $p$, then this implies $x\equiv y\bmod{p}$ by (2). Similarly, writing $x^{p}+(-z)^{p}=(-y)^{p}$ gives then $x\equiv-z\bmod{p}$. However, then $2x^{p}\equiv x^{p}+y^{p}\equiv-x^{p}\bmod{p}$, so $p\,|\,3x^{p}$. Since $p\nmid x$ and $p\neq3$, this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof uses that the ring of integers in the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is a PID for all primes $p<23$. All details are nicely given in Keith Conrad's expose [Fermat's Last Theorem for regular primes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/fltreg.pdf). Note that all primes $p<23$ are regular, because $h_p=1$, as said.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I will have a read through that.